# Diffeomorphically vs holomorphically trivial canonical bundle

Tags: complex-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two definitions of Calabi-Yau manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15003/two-definitions-of-calabi-yau-manifolds)

Given a compact kahler manifold M with diffeomorphically trivial canonical bundle. Is it true that the canonical bundle is also holomorphically trivial ?

What if M is only assumed to be a compact complex manifold ?

Comment: You might want to check out this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15003/two-definitions-of-calabi-yau-manifolds where the first question is answered.

Comment: Rereading Misha Verbitsky's answer to the question I mentioned above seems to also answer the second question.  Hence I'm voting to close as a duplicate.  It's a good question, but it has been asked and answered before.


Comment: Good questions, but I think Jose is correct.

Comment: Dear Jose Figueroa-O'Farrill, thanks for the link above. It answers both questions.

Feel free to close this one.